# Can anyone recommend a CMS to fit the following?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, content-management-system, roles, recommendation-engine

I have a site which is already part built and has some custom features in which I have invested a lot of time in. I now want to add functionality with some kind of CMS. Below are the requirements. I have been searching the web for a relevant CMS but Wordpress seems to be winning it at the moment. I am unsure if Wordpress covers everything I want though.

**CMS requirements**

- Login that covers the whole site. (If logged in, can use custom feature)
- Admin can create custom content types
- CMS that allows CMS features to be dropped in to my current pages (not the other way around)
- Ability to create different user roles
- Lightweight and easy to learn

Wordpress looks good but I am not sure if it fits my requirements. Drupal is too big and bulky. Perch seems too simple.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added wordpress yourself as a tag, so why not do it with wordpress? It is able to do all of that with use of (some obscure) plugins.

For the record: You can use *any* cms and customize it to meet all of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) is a good option as well.  It is a bit more complex than wordpress, but very powerful, very skinable and easy to setup.